# How to make single-digit cents have a leading zero while doing modulus?

Tags: shell

```
RAW_AMT=000078753603
```

I need `amt = 787536.03`

This is the code:

```
AMT=$(${EXPR} ${RAW_AMT} / 100).$(${EXPR} ${RAW_AMT} % 100)
```

but it displays as `AMT = 787536.3`

Comment: Anyone pls help me to fix this

Comment: As an aside -- `EXPR=/bin/expr` or such is bad practice. You may see it in scripts from the 1970s, but it shouldn't ever be used today: `expr` is a builtin in modern shells (actually, it's a builtin even in *ancient* shells; ever since the 1992 publication of POSIX sh, the preferred math syntax is `$(( ))`).

Comment: ...and using `$(expr ...)` is much slower to execute than `$(( ... ))`, as the latter operates using math in the parent shell, whereas the former forks off a separate shell as a subprocess.

Comment: Which shell? There is no single "shell" language…

Comment: @Chris, granted -- though the tag indicates that the default is POSIX. Which means I should actually add a POSIX-baseline version to my answer.

Comment: Part of what makes this tricky, by the way, is that POSIX shells -- including their implementation of `expr` -- are defined with a reference to [the C standard's definition of integer literal formats](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.4.4.1.html), which defines any integer starting with a `0` to be parsed as octal. So a *properly conformant* shell will treat `08 + 1` as an invalid arithmetic operation, for instance, because `8` isn't a valid digit in an octal number.

Comment: (to expand on what I said above: Calling `/bin/expr` or such forces the external command, not the builtin, to be used, making it less efficient. I suppose you could have `EXPR=expr`, but... why?).

Comment: thank you so much Charles Duffy... its working

Answer (score 2):

`printf` can be used to format numbers in any way you choose. In particular, `printf '%02d'` prints a value with two digits, padding with a zero on the left.

Writing this for bash in a robust and efficient manner (no forks, no execs, no implicit temporary files) may look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s extglob              # enable extglob syntax
raw_amt=000078753603          # original input value
unpadded_amt=${raw_amt##+(0)} # trim leading 0's -- otherwise a value that starts with
                              # 0s can be treated as octal rather than decimal.

# use a format string to control formatting of our value
printf -v amt '%d.%02d' "$(( unpadded_amt / 100 ))" "$(( unpadded_amt % 100 ))"

echo "$amt"
```

...or, a less efficient implementation compatible with POSIX sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
raw_amt=000078753603          # original input value

# remove trailing zeros. This requires a fork, but not an exec on any shell
# where expr is builtin
unpadded_amt=$(expr "$raw_amt" : '0*\([^0].*\)$')

# use a format string to control formatting of our value
amt=$(printf '%d.%02d' "$(( unpadded_amt / 100 ))" "$(( unpadded_amt % 100 ))")

echo "$amt"
```

Answer (score 1):

using awk is a bit easier:

```
kent$  raw=000078753603
kent$  awk '{$0*=1;sub(/..$/,".&")}7' <<<$raw
787536.03
```

- `$0*=1` will remove the leading zeros
- `sub(...)` will add a point before `..$`
- `7` a non-zero number, will execute awk's default action, print the result out.

Comment: `<<<$raw` being a bashism is perhaps not ideal, since a specific shell hasn't been given. (My answer has bashisms as well, but I'm trying to work on a POSIX-compliant version... though I might end up just referring folks over to your awk-based answer for a compliant approach, if in fact it were edited to be such; trimming leading 0s in a fully POSIX-compliant manner without invoking subprocesses is tricky).

Comment: Do you mind if I edit to pipe the value into `awk` or use a heredoc rather than a herestring, to make this POSIX-compatible?